# Dynamic UITableViewCell per UILable height with landscape portrait orientation support

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel

I need to create a cell height according to lable's content with orientation support curretly have tried this and working fine for portrait but not in landscape so need solution which works on both so if any one can please help me.

thanks in advance for your efforts.

this is my code in tableview

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *arr = [arrData objectAtIndex:tableView.tag];    
    NSString *text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(contentWidth - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);    
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];    
    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);    
    return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
}
```

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    UILabel *label = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
        [label setTag:1];
        [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];                
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];
    }

    NSArray *arr = [arrData objectAtIndex:tableView.tag];
    NSString *text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(contentWidth - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    if (!label)
        label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    [label setText:text];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, contentWidth - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size.height, 44.0f))];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `heightForRowAtIndexPath` you can set height according to orientation.
when orientation change, reload cells. In `heightForRowAtIndexPath` use this value to check orientation and while this method is called `-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` reload your cells.

So your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` will be somethign like this

```
 if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)){
 }
 else
 {
 }
```

Make sure you keep your cells subviews as autoresizing flexible.